# Jpa Specification json query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want do a select according to values in a json column, using jpa specifications. I'm using postgres 9.6 as db e spring-data-jpa 1.11.

The query could be a little complicated. I could search for strings or numbers or dates.
The query for string type is really simple, but for the other types is a bit complicated.

In postgresql the queries would be:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT json_value ->> 'userId' AS userId FROM my_table) x WHERE cast(x.userid as integer) >2
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT json_value ->> 'userName' AS userName FROM my_table) x WHERE x.userName='xxx'
```

I tried the same code using jpa, but I have some problems with number type.
For the string, the code is:

```
var func = cb.function("json_extract_path_text", String.class,
      root.get(my_table.json_value), cb.literal("userName"));
Predicate predicate = cb.greaterThan(func, "xxx");
return cq.where(predicate).getRestriction();
```

and I haven't problem, while trying the cast for the number:

```
var func = cb.function("json_extract_path_text", String.class,
      root.get(my_table.json_value), cb.literal("userName"));
Predicate predicate = cb.greaterThan(func.as(Integer.class, 2);
return cq.where(predicate).getRestriction();
```

I get this error:

*org.hibernate.QueryException: cast() requires two arguments [select generatedAlias0 from myTable as generatedAlias0 where cast(function('json_extract_path_text', generatedAlias0.json_value, :param0) as integer)>2]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: cast() requires two arguments [select generatedAlias0 from my_table as generatedAlias0 where cast(function('json_extract_path_text', generatedAlias0.json_value, :param0) as integer)>2]*

I tried also to use alias but without good results.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I found the solution. I create a custom function that cast the result of json_extract_path_text and I call in cb.funcion this custom fuction.